# How to pass a value of a variable from an activity to another

Tags: android

From Activity A I open Activity B with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, className.class);
startActivity(intent );
```

Then I have to close Activity B and pass a variable value to Activity A. 
Should I use another intent to call Activity A and pass the variable value with

`intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "message");` ?

Or should I close Activity B with `finish();` and pass the variable value in other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start Activity B from Activity A and in Activity B use `setResult` method to send data back to Activity A . for getting data in Activity A you will need to override `onActivityResult`

Comment: I still didn't get how to pass my variable value from activity B to activity A. Should i use putExtra??

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : plz see [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html) example

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : use        ` Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "message");
      setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);       
      finish();` for sending data back from activity

Comment: Ah ok, then i have to use putextra. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can start activity with `Activity#startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`.

And then make sure you override `protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

Comment: I still didn't get how to pass my variable value from activity B to activity A. Should i use putExtra??

Comment: Yup. In your B activity do that. From your A activity instead of calling B with `startActivity(..)`, call it with `startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_ARBITRARY_REQUEST_CODE);` When your B activity finishes, it will call A's `onActivityResult` with the same `requestCode` you used to call B. `data.getExtra(..)` will contain the value you've put in B ;)

Comment: I made a mistake in my comment. There's no `getExtra(..)`, but `getExtras()` which returns a bundle of returned values. Just check the tutorial linked by @ρяσѕρєя K ;)